# Event Snippet for Google only shows one event while testing on Rich Result Test

Tags: javascript, json-ld, google-rich-snippets, rich-snippets

I want to show my events on Google using Event Snippet for Google and all the examples which i found are only showing example on display one event while i have multiple events to show on snippet.

Below is a sample code for which is not real data but i am testing with this to learn how to implement multiple event

- The Adventures of Kira and Morrison EVENT ONE
- The Adventures of Kira and Morrison EVENT TWO
- The Adventures of Kira and Morrison EVENT THREE

Below code passes when i test it [HERE](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?utm_campaign=devsite&utm_medium=jsonld&utm_source=event&id=ZdFmvofIbV4ZIMJ5KtkShA) but only show one event while it should show all there events
[image]

Below is the code for Snippet using Javascript json+ld format, i would appreciate if someone can help me to fix this so that it will show all three events

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The Adventures of Kira and Morrison</title>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "Event",
      "name": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison EVENT ONE",
      "startDate": "2025-07-21T19:00-05:00",
      "endDate": "2025-07-21T23:00-05:00",
      "eventStatus": "https://schema.org/EventCancelled",
      "eventAttendanceMode": "https://schema.org/OfflineEventAttendanceMode",
      "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "Snickerpark Stadium",
        "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "100 West Snickerpark Dr",
          "addressLocality": "Snickertown",
          "postalCode": "19019",
          "addressRegion": "PA",
          "addressCountry": "US"
        }
      },
      "image": [
        "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
       ],
      "description": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison is coming to Snickertown in a can't miss performance.",
      "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "url": "https://www.example.com/event_offer/12345_201803180430",
        "price": "30",
        "priceCurrency": "USD",
        "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
        "validFrom": "2024-05-21T12:00"
      },
      "performer": {
        "@type": "PerformingGroup",
        "name": "Kira and Morrison"
      },
      "organizer": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Kira and Morrison Music",
        "url": "https://kiraandmorrisonmusic.com"
      }
    },
        {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "Event",
      "name": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison EVENT TWO",
      "startDate": "2025-08-21T19:00-05:00",
      "endDate": "2025-08-21T23:00-05:00",
      "eventStatus": "https://schema.org/EventCancelled",
      "eventAttendanceMode": "https://schema.org/OfflineEventAttendanceMode",
      "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "Snickerpark Stadium",
        "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "100 West Snickerpark Dr",
          "addressLocality": "Snickertown",
          "postalCode": "19019",
          "addressRegion": "PA",
          "addressCountry": "US"
        }
      },
      "image": [
        "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
       ],
      "description": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison is coming to Snickertown in a can't miss performance.",
      "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "url": "https://www.example.com/event_offer/12345_201803180430",
        "price": "30",
        "priceCurrency": "USD",
        "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
        "validFrom": "2024-05-21T12:00"
      },
      "performer": {
        "@type": "PerformingGroup",
        "name": "Kira and Morrison"
      },
      "organizer": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Kira and Morrison Music",
        "url": "https://kiraandmorrisonmusic.com"
      }
    },
        {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "Event",
      "name": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison EVENT THREE",
      "startDate": "2025-09-21T19:00-05:00",
      "endDate": "2025-09-21T23:00-05:00",
      "eventStatus": "https://schema.org/EventCancelled",
      "eventAttendanceMode": "https://schema.org/OfflineEventAttendanceMode",
      "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "Snickerpark Stadium",
        "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "100 West Snickerpark Dr",
          "addressLocality": "Snickertown",
          "postalCode": "19019",
          "addressRegion": "PA",
          "addressCountry": "US"
        }
      },
      "image": [
        "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
       ],
      "description": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison is coming to Snickertown in a can't miss performance.",
      "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "url": "https://www.example.com/event_offer/12345_201803180430",
        "price": "30",
        "priceCurrency": "USD",
        "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
        "validFrom": "2024-05-21T12:00"
      },
      "performer": {
        "@type": "PerformingGroup",
        "name": "Kira and Morrison"
      },
      "organizer": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Kira and Morrison Music",
        "url": "https://kiraandmorrisonmusic.com"
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution which in fact was pretty easy but something things are hard to solve at times as i was not able to find reference regarding this on internet almost all example which i saw showed 1 event in their example..

Multiple events are wrapper in Square Brackets `[]` only then they will show properly.

Below code works fine but in my actual code few warning for optional parameters appears which are due to optional parameters such as `offer, performer` which are not related to this event.

```
<html>
      <head>
        <title>The Adventures of Kira and Morrison</title>
        <script type="application/ld+json">
        [{
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type": "Event",
          "name": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison EVENT ONE",
          "startDate": "2025-07-21T19:00-05:00",
          "endDate": "2025-07-21T23:00-05:00",
          "eventStatus": "https://schema.org/EventCancelled",
          "eventAttendanceMode": "https://schema.org/OfflineEventAttendanceMode",
          "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Snickerpark Stadium",
            "address": {
              "@type": "PostalAddress",
              "streetAddress": "100 West Snickerpark Dr",
              "addressLocality": "Snickertown",
              "postalCode": "19019",
              "addressRegion": "PA",
              "addressCountry": "US"
            }
          },
          "image": [
            "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
            "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
            "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
           ],
          "description": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison is coming to Snickertown in a can't miss performance.",
          "offers": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "url": "https://www.example.com/event_offer/12345_201803180430",
            "price": "30",
            "priceCurrency": "USD",
            "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
            "validFrom": "2024-05-21T12:00"
          },
          "performer": {
            "@type": "PerformingGroup",
            "name": "Kira and Morrison"
          },
          "organizer": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "Kira and Morrison Music",
            "url": "https://kiraandmorrisonmusic.com"
          }
        },
            {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type": "Event",
          "name": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison EVENT TWO",
          "startDate": "2025-08-21T19:00-05:00",
          "endDate": "2025-08-21T23:00-05:00",
          "eventStatus": "https://schema.org/EventCancelled",
          "eventAttendanceMode": "https://schema.org/OfflineEventAttendanceMode",
          "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Snickerpark Stadium",
            "address": {
              "@type": "PostalAddress",
              "streetAddress": "100 West Snickerpark Dr",
              "addressLocality": "Snickertown",
              "postalCode": "19019",
              "addressRegion": "PA",
              "addressCountry": "US"
            }
          },
          "image": [
            "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
            "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
            "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
           ],
          "description": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison is coming to Snickertown in a can't miss performance.",
          "offers": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "url": "https://www.example.com/event_offer/12345_201803180430",
            "price": "30",
            "priceCurrency": "USD",
            "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
            "validFrom": "2024-05-21T12:00"
          },
          "performer": {
            "@type": "PerformingGroup",
            "name": "Kira and Morrison"
          },
          "organizer": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "Kira and Morrison Music",
            "url": "https://kiraandmorrisonmusic.com"
          }
        },
            {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type": "Event",
          "name": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison EVENT THREE",
          "startDate": "2025-09-21T19:00-05:00",
          "endDate": "2025-09-21T23:00-05:00",
          "eventStatus": "https://schema.org/EventCancelled",
          "eventAttendanceMode": "https://schema.org/OfflineEventAttendanceMode",
          "location": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "name": "Snickerpark Stadium",
            "address": {
              "@type": "PostalAddress",
              "streetAddress": "100 West Snickerpark Dr",
              "addressLocality": "Snickertown",
              "postalCode": "19019",
              "addressRegion": "PA",
              "addressCountry": "US"
            }
          },
          "image": [
            "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
            "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
            "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
           ],
          "description": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison is coming to Snickertown in a can't miss performance.",
          "offers": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "url": "https://www.example.com/event_offer/12345_201803180430",
            "price": "30",
            "priceCurrency": "USD",
            "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
            "validFrom": "2024-05-21T12:00"
          },
          "performer": {
            "@type": "PerformingGroup",
            "name": "Kira and Morrison"
          },
          "organizer": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "Kira and Morrison Music",
            "url": "https://kiraandmorrisonmusic.com"
          }
        }]
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
    </html>
```

[image]